How to find current Font Family and Font Size of existing Word Document using .Net Xceed DocX
I am reading a Word document using .Net Xceed DocX library like this:
var result = new MemoryStream();

using (DocX document = DocX.Load(stream))
{
  var paragraphs = document.Paragraphs;
  foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs)
  {
    if (paragraph.Text.Contains("{{Instructions}}"))
    {
      var bulletedList = document.AddList(null, 0, ListItemType.Bulleted);
      document.AddListItem(bulletedList, "Bullet Point 1");
      document.AddListItem(bulletedList, "Bullet Point 2");
      document.AddListItem(bulletedList, "Bullet Point 3");

      paragraph.InsertListAfterSelf(bulletedList);
      paragraph.RemoveText(0);
      break;
    }
  }
  document.SaveAs(result);
}

I search for a term called {{Instructions}} and I want to replace it with a bulleted list. This works but the list has the default font family and font size.
I want to find either the current paragraph's font or the document's font and then pass a Formatting object with these font values to the AddListItem method.
I cannot find the current font family or font size as a property on the paragraph or the document.
I can see these values in the Xml property of the paragraph, so I could extract them from there but that's not ideal.

Xceed DocX Formatting object has a static method called Parse which can take an XElement and brings back a Formatting object.
I needed to use recursion to get a Formatting object with a Font.
var formatting = GetFormatting(paragraph.Xml);  

Formatting GetFormatting(XElement rPr)
{
  var formatting = Formatting.Parse(rPr);
  if(formatting.FontFamily == null)
  {
    formatting = GetFormattingRecursive(rPr, formatting);
  }

  if (formatting.FontFamily == null)
  {
    formatting.FontFamily = new Font("Arial");
  }
  if (formatting.Size == null)
  {
    formatting.Size = 9d;
  }

 return formatting;
}

Formatting GetFormattingRecursive(XElement element, Formatting formatting)
{
  if(element.Elements()?.Any() == true)
  {
    foreach (var e in element.Elements())
    {
      formatting = Formatting.Parse(e);
      if (formatting.FontFamily != null)
      {
        return formatting;
      }
      else
      {
        formatting = GetFormattingRecursive(e, formatting);
      }
    }
  }

  return formatting;
}

